# Update MySql tabel depending on cell values

Tags: mysql

I have a table below with various column.
I want to update the values in certain feilds based on a value on other fields.

My Table is here

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table; 
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
Shot VARCHAR(4),
lay VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
lay_avaibility VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
blk VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
blk_avaibility VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
pri VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
pri_avaibility VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ani VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ani_avaibility VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
status VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'SH01','1863','Offline','1863','Offline','P4645','Offline','P4557','Offline','Over'),
(2,'SH02','1863','Offline','P4645','Offline','P4557','Offline','1863','Offline','Over')
(3,'SH03','P4645','Offline','P4557','Offline','1863','Offline','1863','Offline','WIP'),
(4,'SH04','1863','Offline','P4645','Offline','P4557','Offline','1863','Offline','RTK'),
(5,'SH05','1863','Offline','1863','Offline','P4645','Offline','P4557','Offline','WIP'),
(6,'SH06','P4557','Offline','P4645','Offline','P4645','Offline','P4557','Offline','WIP');

SELECT * FROM my_table;

+----+------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+--------+
| id | Shot | lay   | lay_avaibility | blk   | blk_avaibility | pri   | pri_avaibility | ani   | ani_avaibility | status |
+----+------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+--------+
|  1 | SH01 | 1863  | Offline        | 1863  | Offline        | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | Over   |
|  2 | SH02 | 1863  | Offline        | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | 1863  | Offline        | Over   |
|  3 | SH03 | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | 1863  | Offline        | 1863  | Offline        | WIP    |
|  4 | SH04 | 1863  | Offline        | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | 1863  | Offline        | RTK    |
|  5 | SH05 | 1863  | Offline        | 1863  | Offline        | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | WIP    |
|  6 | SH06 | P4557 | Offline        | P4645 | Offline        | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | WIP    |
+----+------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT VERSION();

+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.23    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

i want to update all lay_avaibility,blk_avaibility,pri_avaibility,ani_avaibility columns to 'Online' where lay,pri,blk,ani columns have '1863' ie., the final table should look like below

```
+----+------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+--------+
| id | Shot | lay   | lay_avaibility | blk   | blk_avaibility | pri   | pri_avaibility | ani   | ani_avaibility | status |
+----+------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+--------+
|  1 | SH01 | 1863  | Online         | 1863  | Online         | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | Over   |
|  2 | SH02 | 1863  | Online         | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | 1863  | Online         | Over   |
|  3 | SH03 | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | 1863  | Online         | 1863  | Online         | WIP    |
|  4 | SH04 | 1863  | Online         | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | 1863  | Online         | RTK    |
|  5 | SH05 | 1863  | Online         | 1863  | Online         | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | WIP    |
|  6 | SH06 | P4557 | Offline        | P4645 | Offline        | P4645 | Offline        | P4557 | Offline        | WIP    |
+----+------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+-------+----------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a CASE statement like this with an Update command:

```
UPDATE my_table 
    SET lay_availability = CASE WHEN lay = '1863' THEN 'Online' ELSE lay_availability END,
    blk_availability = CASE WHEN blk = '1863' THEN 'Online' ELSE blk_availability END,
    pri_availability = CASE WHEN pri = '1863' THEN 'Online' ELSE pri_availability END,
    ani_avaibility   = CASE WHEN ani = '1863' THEN 'Online' ELSE ani_avaibility END;
```

Comment: Sol,
It having minor issue also.
This is updating other that '1863' to 'Offline' that should not happen. It Should only effect '1863' relevant cells

Comment: Take a look at the answer now, I updated it to keep the existing value of the column and only update it if the corresponding column is 1863.  That should fix the problem you were having.

Comment: if confused with my question i am sorry.
I want only '1863' records to be updated and others should be intact. They should not get updated.
Some times P4557 or P4645 may also be 'Online' But this Statement is making '1863' to 'Online' and others to 'Offline'

Comment: Worked Perfectly...
Thx for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
update my_table
set lay_avaibility = 'online',
blk_avaibility = 'online',
pri_avaibility = 'online',
ani_avaibility = 'online'
where (lay = 1863 or
blk = 1863 or 
ani =1863);
```

Comment: Same answer as Sashi Kanth above.
This is even updating other cells which are having 'p4645'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  UPDATE my_table 
SET lay_availability = CASE WHEN lay = '1863' THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Offline' END,
blk_availability = CASE WHEN blk = '1863' THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Offline' END,
pri_availability = CASE WHEN pri = '1863' THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Offline' END,
ani_avaibility   = CASE WHEN ani = '1863' THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Offline' END;
```

Comment: but i added `ani_avaibility`

Comment: your are write, but he missed it. any one can assume it and add.
any how thx for your answer